# Show Updated Server Time in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, timer

I'm trying to get a running clock of the servers current time to show the user.  I currently have it showing to the user but every time the UpdatePanel updates the label with the new time it does a post back of the entire page.

The ASP.net code is as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateTime" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblServerTime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
       <asp:Timer ID="timer" Interval="1000" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my VB code behind is:

```
    Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
    lblServerTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("f", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This should work fine. What browser you are using?

Comment: I'm using IE 8, but it also does the same thing in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solutions above but I couldn't get them to work. Here's how I solved it though:

```
<label id="lblServerTime"></label>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var serverTimeMillisecond = "<%= DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds %>";
   localTime = new Date();
   offset = localTime.setMilliseconds(localTime.getMilliseconds() - serverTimeMillisecond);
   function runClock() {
      var time = new Date();
      time.setMilliseconds(localTime.getMilliseconds() + offset);
      document.getElementById("lblServerTime").innerHTML = time;
      setTimeout(runClock, 1000);
   }
   runClock();
```

Also, if you are going to put the value into an asp.net you need to use the ClientID as the ID ex:

```
document.getElementByID("<%= lblServerTime.ClientID %>").innerHTML = someValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making an asynchronous request to the server to get the time on an interval instead of using the update panel, like this:

Markup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('getServerTime()', 1000);
});

function getServerTime() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/GetServerTime",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
           // Replace the DIV's content with the page method's return value
           $("#results").text(result.d);
       }
    });
}

<div id="results"></div>
```

---

> Note: `setInterval()` will fire every 1000 milleseconds (1 second) again and again.

---

Code-behind:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function GetServerTime() As String
    Return DateTime.Now.ToString("f", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
End Function
```

Comment: I was trying your code, but I think I am running into a problem implementing.  I have put in the code behind, but when the JavaScript runs it is giving me the error: "Line: 2832
Error: 'Sys.Res.createNoDom' is null or not an object" I should also mention this code is running in a Web User Control

Comment: Is the URL correct if the file it is on is name serverTime.ascx and the URL is -> url: "serverTime.ascx/GetServerTime" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateTime" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblServerTime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
       <asp:Timer ID="timer" Interval="1000" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="Tick" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Add Trigger in your update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Am not good in vb, just am saying the theme using c#. You may get idea from this. You need to use triggers, so that tick event gets fire with timer.

**HTML**

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                  </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                  <asp:Timer ID="updtimer" runat="server" interval="1000" ontick="updtimer_Tick">
                  </asp:Timer>
                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpanel" runat="server">
                  <Triggers>
                     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="updtimer" eventname="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="timedate" runat="server" 
                      Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void updtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timedate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss tt ");
}
```

That's all. You will get the running time by using this. Let me know if you get stuck again.
Happy coding.